# Linux VAS Management

Tags: kernel

Where in the line of code which alternates between virtual address spaces (vas) in the Linux kernel? I know Linux describes the vas with struct mm_struct, but can't find the actual code.

Comment: Did you try looking at the stuff that manipulates the LDT?

Comment: Come again. Do you mean looking in the LDT.c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I do not possess in-depth knowledge about the Linux kernel, I think looking at code in `mm/memory.c` ( http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.0.4/mm/memory.c ) could provide you some pointers for what you are looking for. LDT mentioned by @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams is specifically for x86's Local Descriptor Table the code for which is present in `arch/x86/kernel/ldt.c`. Browsing through the source will be the best option to learn more I guess.
Hope this helps!